# How to properly store end date in database

Tags: java, javascript, date, datetime, extjs

Application: Java + ExtJS

There are a lot of different entity with properties of java.util.Date type: startDate and iesendDate (endDate could be NULL). Both dates could be selected with or without time part (e.g. time part is always persisted, event if it is not selected). For example, like this:

```
2010-07-01 00:00:00
```

Possible problems start when user selects endDate without time. For example, period starts on 2010-07-01 and ends on 1010-07-04. Right now in database it is stored like:

```
startDate="2010-07-01 00:00:00"
endDate="2010-07-04 00:00:00".
```

So it seems that period ends on the FIRST second of 2010-07-04. But as  user assume, that endDate is implicitly included, e.g. period ends on LAST second of 2010-07-04. There are a lot of date comparisons for different periods in the system.

How in this case to store end date properly?

I thought about possible solutions, but all of them seems a bit wrong:

1. To store time part for end date like this: "2010-07-04 23:59:99". But then seems that end date day is not 24h - but (24h - 0.(9) millisecond), that could be potential problem. Also time part looks quite ugly.
2. To modify ExtJs component that it will add 1 day to date selected by user on persistance stage and substract 1 day again when this date will be shown to user (except cases when the user explicitly set time part). I don't like here that dates with time part and without it are treated differently.
3. To save only start date as Date object, and then save length of period in seconds, for example. This approach seems quite good - but a have to rework the whole application and possible it will be no very easy to use different comparisons on end dates.
4. Just use current one - save non-enclusive end date without time and be very careful during dates comparisons

Could someone explain the most widely used practices to solve such problem?

Answer (score 2):

I've recently changed from your first approach to your second approach.

Approach 1: "2010-07-04 23:59:99" should be "2010-07-04 23:59:59" but anyway it is indeed ugly and technically there is a lost second. Another issue I did have is that I wanted to start one record with the same data/time as another record was stopped. So it was possible to find the successor of a record. And with approach 1 this cannot be done as the time will differentiate 1 second.

Approach 2: The end date will be "2010-07-05" and the query condition will be `< endDate` instead of `<= endDate` for approach 1. Here the end date is meaning 'till' or 'until' or 'up to' and not like in approach 1 'up to and including'. For this reason in new projects I do use tillDate or actually I use something like serviceStart / serviceTill.

The disadvantage is indeed to format it -1 day when showing to the user. But for me this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Add end date as +1 day of user selected value.

Answer (score 0):

### Separate model and presentation

Do separate the stored end time in your database completely from the presentation of the end time to the user.

**Store end date and time in database:** Since you always store both date and time, you should clearly store the true date and time. If the period end at midnight between July 4 and 5, store this time, so `2010-07-05 00:00:00`.

**Present to the user:** How your user would like to see that end time, I cannot say, and you should ask the users themselves. Maybe they will tell you:

- As it is. `2010-07-05 00:00:00`.
- As 24 hours on the last day of the period,  `2010-07-04 24:00:00`.
- As the last day as date only `2010-07-04` (I consider this unlikely, especially of the start time is not at midnight).
- Or something else.

So yes, it’s very likely that you will have to treat end at midnight specially *for presentation*. It is not nearly as bad as if you had needed to treat it specially *in your business logic*.